# Как правильно сохранять файлы на сервере

Tags: c#

Необходимо реализовать хранение файлов на сервере.

Есть клиент, который отправляет на сервер файлы в виде массива байтов, но меня волнует вопрос - как правильно сохранять эти файлы.

1. Хранить ли эти файлы в базе данных в какой-нибудь таблице "Files" (собственно, сам массив байт). Пример столбцов в таблице: Id (Guid), Name (Text), File (Text)

- Id - уникальный идентификатор для строки таблицы
- Name - название программы
- File - файл, преобразованный в массив байт

или же

2. Хранить их в виде файлов в какой-нибудь папке на сервере, а в базу данных создавать запись только о том, куда этот файл был сохранён (пример столбцов в таблице, как это вижу я: Id (Guid), Name (Text), Path (Name), Revision (Int))

- Id - уникальный идентификатор для строки таблицы
- Name - название программы
- Path - путь до программы
- Revision - "версия" файла

UPD:

Конечная цель - создание модуля программы для совместного редактирования файлов. Пример: клиент редактирует файл, сохраняет его, отправляет на сервер - остальные клиенты видят, что версия файла изменилась, и они могут скачать его. Из-за нехватки знаний в области работы с файлами не могу точно спрогнозировать, какой подход окажется удобнее в будущем. Хотелось-бы выбрать наиболее удачный, чтобы не пришлось в дальнейшем придумывать костыли

Comment: Все зависит от ваших требований, оба варианта имеют право на жизнь

Comment: @tym32167 Конечная цель - создание модуля программы для совместного редактирования файлов. Пример: клиент редактирует файл, сохраняет его, отправляет на сервер - остальные клиенты видят, что версия файла изменилась, и они могут скачать его. Из-за нехватки знаний в области работы с файлами не могу точно спрогнозировать, какой подход окажется удобнее в будущем. Хотелось-бы выбрать наиболее удачный, чтобы не пришлось в дальнейшем придумывать костыли

Comment: @Кирилл добавьте это в вопрос

Comment: Если файлы важные, то наверное вам понадобится версионирование, история изменений, бекапы и все подобное. Если вам все это надо, то просто файлы не очень подходят.

Comment: @Кирилл какой подход? "Система контроля версий". И ваш пример не про совместное редактирование. Совместное редактирование - это сколько угодно пользователей могут редактировать один и тот же файл одновременно и видеть все изменения в режиме реального времени. Гуглодоки как пример.